# Is there any way to shorten this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query below, its working fine, and I'm getting what I need. All I need to know is, is this right way to write this query as this or is there any way to shorten it?

I have 4 tables, 1st has branch information, 2nd has customer information, 3rd has engineer information, 4th has service calls information.

In service calls table, 3 columns match with 3 different engineer names

Here is the query

```
SELECT
    B.BranchName, C.Name AS CustomerName,D.FullName AS CallOpenedBy,
    A.CallOpenTime, A.CallMode, A.CallType, A.ReportedBy, 
    A.ReportedVia, A.ReportedProblem,
    A.MaterialsReceived, A.MisComments, A.CallPriority, A.EstimatedAmount,
    E.FullName AS EngineerName,  
    A.ActionTaken, A.CallClosedTime, 
    F.FullName AS CallClosedBy, A.Status, 
    A.Amount 
FROM
    TblServiceCalls A
INNER JOIN 
    TblBranchInfo B ON A.BranchID = B.BranchID
INNER JOIN 
    TblMainMaster C ON A.MasterID = C.MasterID
INNER JOIN 
    TblUserProfiles D ON A.CallOpenedBy = D.UserProID
INNER JOIN 
    TblUserProfiles E ON  A.Engineer = E.UserProID
INNER JOIN 
    TblUserProfiles F ON  A.CallClosedBy = F.UserProID
```

Can I shorten the query in last 3 lines? Thanks you guys in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not, you are using `D`, `E`, and `F` in your result set so you must join those tables. You could only remove them if you removed things like `D.FullName AS CallOpenedBy` and `E.FullName AS

EngineerName` and `F.FullName AS CallClosedBy` from your result.

---

As a side note (and the I bet the original reason you asked this question), but if a call has not been closed yet and `A.CallClosedBy` has not been assigned to a value in `F.UserProID` the row will be excluded from the result.

You should be using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for those 3 tables if any of the 3 columns they link on may not have a corresponding record in the destination table or could be null.

Here is how I would do it

```
Select B.BranchName, C.Name AS CustomerName,IsNull(D.FullName, '(Not Assigned)') AS CallOpenedBy,
A.CallOpenTime,A.CallMode, A.CallType,A.ReportedBy, A.ReportedVia, A.ReportedProblem,
A.MaterialsReceived, A.MisComments,A.CallPriority,A.EstimatedAmount,IsNull(E.FullName, '(Not Assigned)') AS        
EngineerName, A.ActionTaken, A.CallClosedTime,IsNull(F.FullName, '(Not Assigned)') AS CallClosedBy, A.Status, 
A.Amount From TblServiceCalls A
INNER JOIN TblBranchInfo B ON A.BranchID = B.BranchID
INNER JOIN TblMainMaster C ON A.MasterID = C.MasterID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TblUserProfiles D ON A.CallOpenedBy = D.UserProID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TblUserProfiles E ON  A.Engineer = E.UserProID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TblUserProfiles F ON  A.CallClosedBy = F.UserProID
```

Now if the value is `NULL` or the record does not exist in the destination table it will say `(Not Assigned)` in the output instead of excluding the row.

Comment: Thanks, You no need to bet, Actually i Havent considered that part if the call has not been closed!. And really thanks for the good Explanation. Have a good day